# Is it possible to allow didSet to be called during initialization in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, didset

#### Question

[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_368) specify that:

> willSet and didSet observers are not called when a property is first initialized. They are only called when the property’s value is set outside of an initialization context.

Is it possible to force these to be called during initialization?

#### Why?

Let's say I have this class

```
class SomeClass {
    var someProperty: AnyObject {
        didSet {
            doStuff()
        }
    }

    init(someProperty: AnyObject) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
        doStuff()
    }

    func doStuff() {
        // do stuff now that someProperty is set
    }
}
```

I created the method `doStuff`, to make the processing calls more concise, but I'd rather just process the property within the `didSet` function.  Is there a way to force this to call during initialization?

#### Update

I decided to just remove the convenience intializer for my class and force you to set the property after initialization.  This allows me to know `didSet` will always be called.  I haven't decided if this is better overall, but it suits my situation well.

Comment: it is honestly best just to "accept this is how swift works".  if you put an inline initialization value on the var statement, of course that does not call "didSet".  that's why the "init()" situation must also not call "didSet".  it all makes sense.

Comment: @Logan The question itself answered my question ;) thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the convenience initializer, you can combine it with `defer`:
`convenience init(someProperty: AnyObject) {
  self.init()
  defer {
    self.someProperty = someProperty
  }
`

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Create an own set-Method and use it within your init-Method:

```
class SomeClass {
    var someProperty: AnyObject! {
        didSet {
            //do some Stuff
        }
    }

    init(someProperty: AnyObject) {
        setSomeProperty(someProperty)
    }

    func setSomeProperty(newValue:AnyObject) {
        self.someProperty = newValue
    }
}
```

> By declaring `someProperty` as type: `AnyObject!` (an implicitly
>   unwrapped optional), you allow self to fully initialize without
>   `someProperty` being set. When you call
>   `setSomeProperty(someProperty)` you're calling an equivalent of
>   `self.setSomeProperty(someProperty)`. Normally you wouldn't be able to
>   do this because self hasn't been fully initialized. Since
>   `someProperty` doesn't require initialization and you are calling a
>   method dependent on self, Swift leaves the initialization context and
>   didSet will run.

Comment: Why would this differ from self.someProperty = newValue in the init? Have you got a working test case?

Comment: Don't know why it works -- but it does. Directly setting the new value within the init()-Method doesn't call didSet() -- but using the given Method setSomeProperty() does.

Comment: I think I know what's happening here. By declaring `someProperty` as type: `AnyObject!` (an implicitly unwrapped optional), you allow `self` to fully initialize without `someProperty` being set.  When you call `setSomeProperty(someProperty)` you're calling an equivalent of `self.setSomeProperty(someProperty)`.  Normally you wouldn't be able to do this because `self` hasn't been fully initialized.  Since `someProperty` doesn't require initialization and you are calling a method dependent on `self`, Swift leaves the initialization context and `didSet` will run.

Comment: It looks like anything that is set outside of the actual init() DOES get didSet called. Literally anything that is not set `init() { *HERE* }` will have didSet called. Great for this question but using a secondary function to set some values leads to didSet being called. Not great if you want to reuse that setter function.

Comment: @Mark seriously, trying to apply common sense or  logic to Swift is just absurd. But you can trust the upvotes or try it yourself. I just did and it works. And yes, it makes no sense at all.

Comment: This isn't horrible.  Since the `setSomeProperty()` method is only used as a work-around for what can't be done in `init()`, you could just as well name it `lateInit()` or `start()` or `begin()` or `ignition()` and just use that for any post-member-value-initialization stuff you want to run when the object is created.

Comment: @Logan is correct. You can test out his theory for yourself by trying to set a non-optional property after calling the method. It won't work since you need to initialize all properties before you can use self.

Comment: @Logan Your observation is *almost* correct. Whenever you have `var x : String?` then automatically `x` **is** set to `nil` (same **isn't** true if you used `let` instead of `var`). Same is true for `var x : String!`. The only difference is this time if you access *when* it's `nil` you will crash. If you don't access it, it doesn't mean that it's value isn't set. It means it's `nil` but you're not messing with it to create an error. For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797351/class-has-no-initializers-swift/40769917#40769917). Make sure you see the links at the end.

Comment: @Logan You can always 'initialize' a class with implicitly unwrapped optionals. What you can't do is access them safely. You can only access them after it's value is changed from `nil` to a non-nil value. FWIW it having a value of `nil` doesn't mean it's not set. It **is** set, but set to `nil`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in latest version of Xcode and Swift

Answer (score 387):

If you use `defer` inside of an *initializer*, for updating any optional properties or further updating non-optional properties that you've already initialized and after you've called any `super.init()` methods, then your `willSet`, `didSet`, etc. will be called.  I find this to be more convenient than implementing separate methods that you have to keep track of calling in the right places.

For example:

```
public class MyNewType: NSObject {

    public var myRequiredField:Int

    public var myOptionalField:Float? {
        willSet {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                print("I'm going to change to \(newValue)")
            }
        }
        didSet {
            if let myOptionalField = self.myOptionalField {
                print("Now I'm \(myOptionalField)")
            }
        }
    }

    override public init() {
        self.myRequiredField = 1

        super.init()

        // Non-defered
        self.myOptionalField = 6.28

        // Defered
        defer {
            self.myOptionalField = 3.14
        }
    }
}
```

Will yield:

```
I'm going to change to 3.14
Now I'm 3.14
```

Comment: Cheeky little trick, I like it... weird quirk of Swift though.

Comment: Great. You found another useful case of using `defer`. Thanks.

Comment: Great use of defer! Wish I could give you more than one upvote.

Comment: very interesting.. I've never seen defer used like this before. It's eloquent and works.

Comment: But you set myOptionalField twice which isn't great from performance perspective. What if heavy calculations takes place?

Comment: @YakivKovalsky agreed that there's a small amount of extra overhead with this design.  But, I think you'll just have to use some judgement there on the performance impact for your specific use case.  I would almost always use this on an optional field where the initial assignment is nil and requires no calculation.  So, there should, at least, not be wasted calculation.

Comment: JUST AMAZING, THANKS

Comment: can't argue with that!  nice!

Comment: This only works for classes, not structs.

Answer (score 85):

As a variation of Oliver's answer, you could wrap the lines in a closure. Eg:

```
class Classy {

    var foo: Int! { didSet { doStuff() } }

    init( foo: Int ) {
        // closure invokes didSet
        ({ self.foo = foo })()
    }

}
```

Edit: Brian Westphal's answer is nicer imho. The nice thing about his is that it hints at the intent.

Comment: That's clever and does not pollute the class with redundant methods.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Worth noting that in Swift 2.2 you need to wrap the closure in parentheses always.

Comment: @Max Cheers, the sample include parens now

Comment: Clever answer! One note: if your class is a subclass of something else, you will need to call super.init() before ({ self.foo = foo })()

Comment: @Hlung, I don't get a feeling it's more likely to break in future than anything else, but there is still the problem that without commenting the code it's not very clear what it does. At least Brian's "defer" answer gives the reader a hint that we want to perform the code after initialization.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and this works for me

```
class SomeClass {
    var someProperty: AnyObject {
        didSet {
            doStuff()
        }
    }

    init(someProperty: AnyObject) {
        defer { self.someProperty = someProperty }
    }

    func doStuff() {
        // do stuff now that someProperty is set
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you get it?

Comment: This approach no longer works. The compiler throws two errors: 
– 'self' used in method call '$defer' before all stored properties are initialized
– Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: You're right but there's a workaround. You only need to declare someProperty as implicit unwrapped or optional and supply it will a default value with nil coalescing  to avoid failures. 

tldr; someProperty must be an optional type

Answer (score 2):

This works if you do this in a subclass

```
class Base {

  var someProperty: AnyObject {
    didSet {
      doStuff()
    }
  }

  required init() {
    someProperty = "hello"
  }

  func doStuff() {
    print(someProperty)
  }
}

class SomeClass: Base {

  required init() {
    super.init()

    someProperty = "hello"
  }
}

let a = Base()
let b = SomeClass()
```

In `a` example, `didSet` is not triggered. But in `b` example, `didSet` is triggered, because it is in the subclass. It has to do something with what `initialization context` really means, in this case the `superclass` did care about that

Comment: Hi @onmyway133
swift being a type safe language always fully initialized a type else not.
When you initialized someClass. Base class being fully initialized and then in SomeClass you are setting someProperty = "hello". 
Hence didSet being called

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a solution, an alternative way of going about it would be using a class constructor:

```
class SomeClass {
    var someProperty: AnyObject {
        didSet {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    class func createInstance(someProperty: AnyObject) -> SomeClass {
        let instance = SomeClass() 
        instance.someProperty = someProperty
        return instance
    }  
}
```

Comment: This solution would require you to change the optionality of `someProperty` since it won't have given it a value during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular case where you want to invoke `willSet` or `didSet` inside `init` for a property available in your superclass, you can simply assign your super property directly:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // this will call `willSet` and `didSet`
    someProperty = super.someProperty
}
```

Note that [Charlesism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29501998/1033581) solution with a closure would always work too in that case. So my solution is just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, didSet observers aren't called when a root class is initialized.

If your class isn't a subclass, you have to use getters and setters to achieve the functionality you want:

```
class SomeClass {
    private var _test: Int = 0
    var test: Int {
        get { _test }
        set { _test = newValue }
    }
    
    init(test: Int) { self.test = test }
}
```

alternatively, if your class is a subclass, you can use didSet and do:

```
override init(test: int) {
    super.init()
    self.test = test
}
```

The didSet SHOULD get called after super.init() is called.

One thing I have not tried but MIGHT also work:

```
init(test: int) {
    defer { self.test = test }
}
```

**NOTE:** you will need to make your properties nullable, or set a default value for them, or unwrap the class properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it in obj-с way:

```
class SomeClass {
    private var _someProperty: AnyObject!
    var someProperty: AnyObject{
        get{
            return _someProperty
        }
        set{
            _someProperty = newValue
            doStuff()
        }
    }
    init(someProperty: AnyObject) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
        doStuff()
    }

    func doStuff() {
        // do stuff now that someProperty is set
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @yshilov, I don't think this really solves the problem I was hoping to since technically, when you call `self.someProperty` you're leaving initialization scope.  I believe the same thing could be accomplished by doing `var someProperty: AnyObject! = nil { didSet { ... } }`.  Still, some might appreciate it as a work around, thanks for the addition

Comment: @Logan nope, that will not work. didSet will be completely ignored in init().