# Class has no initializers Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a problem with Swift class. I have a swift file for UITableViewController class and UITableViewCell class. My problem is the UITableViewCell class, and outlets. This class has an error **Class "HomeCell" has no initializers**, and I don't understand this problem.

Thanks for your responses.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HomeTable: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableViex: UITableView!

    var items: [(String, String, String)] = [
        ("Test", "123", "1.jpeg"),
        ("Test2", "236", "2.jpeg"),
        ("Test3", "678", "3.jpeg")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var nib = UINib(nibName: "HomeCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "bookCell")
    }

    // Number row
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    // Style Cell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bookCell") as UITableViewCell

        // Style here

        return cell

    }

    // Select row
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // Select
    }

}

// PROBLEM HERE
class HomeCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imgBook: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet var titleBook: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var pageBook: UILabel

    func loadItem(#title: String, page: String, image:String) {
        titleBook.text = title
        pageBook.text = page
        imgBook.image = UIImage(named: image)
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to explicitly state the type of the nib variable as an optional UINib?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You have to use implicitly unwrapped optionals so that Swift can cope with circular dependencies (parent <-> child of the UI components in this case) during the initialization phase.

```
@IBOutlet var imgBook: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var titleBook: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var pageBook: UILabel!
```

Read this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_98), they explain it all nicely.

Comment: Your explanation, and that doc, all make sense to me, but not the error message!

Comment: That's probably a question for Apple

Comment: Also @IBOutlets should be marked as weak in order to avoid retain cycle.

Comment: @Dennis Pashkov As far as I know, it's only for IBOutlets that is in viewController's view hierarchy. Otherwise it will get released immediately because no one hold it.

Comment: I had this problem where I defined a Bool using `var myBool: Bool`.

Comment: The responses to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24006975/885189) provide some good examples/explanations of using `Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals` as well.

Comment: About "cope with circular dependencies". From this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) do you mean this title: "Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties" and *under the hood* your imgBook, titleBook, pageBook are hooked with `unowned`?

Comment: You can also define IBOutlets as weak properties since you don't want anyone hanging on to them once your Viewcontroller is deallocated.

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. If you initialize an object with a property that is **not** an optional, then it has to be set with the object. Anything initialized later has to be an optional, since it will be `nil` for a period of time in which you can access that property. That's the reason of the message: it doesn't have an initializer that sets the initial value for that particular property.

Answer (score 101):

Quick fix - make sure all variables which do not get initialized when they are created (eg `var num : Int?` vs `var num = 5`) have either a `?` or `!`.

Long answer (reccomended) - read the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_98) as per mprivat suggests...

Comment: To resolve this error you need to set up default value for ? variables, for example: let showUserPointViewDelegate : ShowUserPointsViewControllerControl? = nil

Comment: +1 `?` means it may be nil, but if it was then there is no problem with moving forward and doing nothing. `!` means if after unwrapping it was nil, then crash—both of these **satisfy the initiation requirement** —by you informing the compiler: I know/want that it will start form nil.

Comment: Search for `var` and `let` in you view controller, and look for missing `!`s and `?`s

Answer (score 34):

<sub>My answer addresses the error in general and not the exact code of the OP. No answer mentioned this note so I just thought I add it.</sub>

The code below would also generate the **same** error:

```
class Actor {
    let agent : String? // BAD! // Its value is set to nil, and will always be nil and that's stupid so Xcode is saying not-accepted.  
    // Technically speaking you have a way around it, you can help the compiler and enforce your value as a constant. See Option3
}
```

Others mentioned that *Either you create initializers or you make them optional types, using ! or ?* which is correct. However if you have an optional member/property, that optional should be mutable ie **`var`**. If you make a `let` then it would *never* be able to get out of its `nil` state. That's bad!

So the correct way of writing it is:

### Option1

```
class Actor {
    var agent : String? // It's defaulted to `nil`, but also has a chance so it later can be set to something different || GOOD!
}
```

Or you can write it as:

### Option2

```
class Actor {
let agent : String? // It's value isn't set to nil, but has an initializer || GOOD!

init (agent: String?){
    self.agent = agent // it has a chance so its value can be set!
    }
}
```

or default it to any value (including `nil` which is kinda stupid)

### Option3

```
class Actor {
let agent : String? = nil // very useless, but doable.
let company: String? = "Universal" 
}
```

---

<sub>If you are curious as to why `let` (contrary to `var`) isn't initialized to `nil` then read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400196/why-optional-constant-does-not-automatically-have-a-default-value-of-nil) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145422/when-an-instance-of-a-class-is-initialized-what-is-the-sequence)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for adding this as it was a critical part of the picture.

Comment: Well explained!!

Comment: Setting to nil is not stupid, but inherent to how many models work.

Comment: @drew.. setting something immutable to `nil` is very wrong. Setting a `var` to `nil` is a different thing.

Comment: hey Honey, who was speaking to immutable objects?

Comment: `class Actor {
let agent : String? = nil // very useless, but doable.
}` @drew.. when would you setup a model like this? Where it can never become non-nil?

Answer (score 32):

This is from Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID220)

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.

You get the error message **Class "HomeCell" has no initializers** because your variables is in an indeterminate state. Either you create initializers or you make them optional types, using ! or ?

Answer (score 12):

In my case I have declared a `Bool` like this:

```
var isActivityOpen: Bool
```

i.e. I declared it without unwrapping so, This is how I solved the (*no initializer*) error :

```
var isActivityOpen: Bool!
```

Comment: Why not give it an initial value? Otherwise your app will crash if you try to access the property before you assign some value somewhere. `var isActivityOpen = false`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a specific answer to your question but I had got this error when I hadn't set an initial value for an enum while declaring it as a property. I assigned a initial value to the enum to resolve this error.
Posting here as it might help someone.

Answer (score -1):

simply provide the init block for **HomeCell** class

it's work in my case

Answer (score -1):

In my case I have declared a variable age in class like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var age:Int

}
```

i.e. Later, I understood that the class has no initializers, and I made changes to give a value to the age variable. We have two options:

1. We have to give a value to the variable:

   `var age:Int = 0`
2. "Or, we can unwrap the variable:"

   `var age:Int!`