# Class has no initializers despite force unwraping IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, swift, class, swift4

I have a class in swift with the following signature:

```
class CommentsVC: UITableViewController {
```

Giving me:

> Class 'CommentsVC' has no initializers

It has the two bellow IBOutlets as well as two IBActions:

```
@IBOutlet weak var AddCommentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var AddingCommentTextField: UITextField!
```

I also have two table view methods:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

And

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254941/cant-figure-out-why-i-am-getting-class-viewcontroller-has-no-initializers-err?noredirect=1&lq=1) however it does not work for this situation as I already do what they recommend.

**What is going wrong and how can I fix it?**

**Update:**

The below code seems to be the problem. On the other VC, which uses a prepare method to pass over this data, I am passing in a post object which is initialized the same way I am initializing the problematic code below. How do I fix this?

```
var selectedMedia : Media {
    didSet {
        self.comments = selectedMedia.comments
        loadComments()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is pretty simple to solve. All you have to do is add a force unwrap or an optional like so:

```
var selectedMedia : Media! /*or, ?*/ {
    didSet {
        self.comments = selectedMedia.comments
        loadComments()
    }
}
```

You'll get some errors, these will be easy just press fix from suggested options to fix them (basically they will say add an "!" etc..)

Comment: Also remember to add the "!" infront of selectedMedia[here].comments...

Answer (score 0):

Just add an initial value for var selectedMedia, something like this:

```
var selectedMedia: Media = Media() {
    didSet {
        self.comments = selectedMedia.comments
        loadComments()
    }
}
```

or you can make selectedMedia optional: Media! or Media?