# Why optional constant does not automatically have a default value of nil

Tags: swift, option-type

The following code works fine

```
struct carConfi {
    var owner: String?
    let brand: String = "BMW"
    var currentMile: Double = 2000
}

let tomCar = carConfi()
```

However, if I change the type of the property `owner` to constant, there will be an error at the initializer

```
struct carConfi {
        let owner: String? // Change to constant
        let brand: String = "BMW"
        var currentMile: Double = 2000
    }

let tomCar = carConfi() //error: missing argument for parameter 'owner' in call
```

I did a bit search, it turns out that it is because the *optional* variables automatically have a default value of nil

**I guess:** Because once the constant is set, it then cannot be changed, if the optional constant automatically received an `nil` then it will keep as an unchangeable `nil` that's very silly and may against the users will

**Question:** My college doesn't fully convinced by the guess, he told me there must be more reasons for that. I would very appreciate if someone can explain that to me

Thx

Comment: Your guess is right. What possible use case would there be for defaulting a `let` value to `nil`? But it is a very likely mistake, so having an error there is certainly helpful.

Comment: You can boil this example down to `let foo:String?; print(foo)` vs `var foo:String?; print(foo)` btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not setting a read-only (constant) field with either an:

- initialization expression
- initializer

is almost certainly an indication of an error in your program.

Since you have no other opportunity to set the value of your `let` field, the value of the field is going to remain `nil` (or some other default). It is rather unlikely that a programmer would find such behavior desirable, and request it on purpose.

That is why Swift marks this situation as an error. On the other hand, if you actually wanted your `String` constant to remain `nil`, you could add an expression to set it to `nil`, and silence the error:

```
let owner: String? = nil // Pretty useless, but allowed
```

Comment: It doesn't seem unreasonable for *certain* initializers to set the value, and for others to ignore the property  (and have it set to the default of `nil`). The mentioned `let owner: String? = nil` wouldn't allow this behavior either.

Comment: `let`s that default to nil would allow for a subclass to inherit its superclass's initializers. Using `var` allows this. But add a `let` to a subclass and you then need to override the superclass initializers.

Comment: I completely understood your answer, I just understand your terminology. what do you mean by *initialization expression* you mean `String? = nil`? and by *initializer* you mean `init (owner: String){ self.ownder = ownder}` ?

Comment: @Honey Correct, initialization expression is what follows `=` in `let owner: String? = nil`. In this case, initialization expression is `nil`, and initializaer is any overload of `init`.

Answer (score 3):

Constants are set once, and once only. If you wanted it to be null or 0, then you would set it. You always define a constant on initiation.