# initialize a struct without the optionals properties

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, initialization, option-type

I want to be able to create an object of this struct without having to initialize the 2 optional doubles
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i5Sx.png)

Comment: Please post your code as *text* not as a screenshot.

Comment: Looks like  a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38942325/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use default value for the properties.

```
init(presentValue: Double, rate: Double, time: Double, frequency: Double = 0.0) {
...
}
```

Comment: thank you. Needed to add the argument "futureValue : Double = 0.0" though