# Unable to declare a constant as optional in swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have below code.I am trying to declare a 'name' constant as optional but it does not allow it gives error as

> stored property 'name' without initial value prevents synthesized
>   initializers

```
class VideoMode {

    let resolution = Resolution()
    var interlaced = false
    var frameRate:Float = 0.0
    let name: String?
}
```

EDIT:Why i am getting such error as in case of structure it will not give any error

Comment: A 'nil' constant which never will change is nonsensical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just too something-or-other

Comment: @matt, "Too something-or-other?" LOL. Too silly, perhaps?

Comment: I consider it as a valid question. Valid, concrete issue, clearly stated, code shown.

Comment: @matt: Why do you vote to close as off-topic *and* answer it? Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq: *"Answering off-topic questions, promotes the idea that these questions are acceptable questions to ask, thus leading to more off-topic questions."*

Comment: Related: [Why optional constant does not automatically have a default value of nil](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37400196/2976878)

Comment: @MartinR For the same reason that you do.

Answer (score 2):

You have to say

```
var name: String?
```

*or* you must assign `name` a value or have an *initializer* (`init`) that initializes `name`.

Thus, this is legal:

```
class VideoMode {
    let name: String?
    init(name:String) {self.name = name}
}
```

and this is legal:

```
class VideoMode {
    let name: String? = "howdy"
}
```

but this is not legal:

```
class VideoMode {
    let name: String? // compile error
}
```

The reason is obvious. If `name` is a `let`, and you don't initialize it, it can *never* be set, because it is a constant. The compiler won't let that sort of silly situation exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write like this-

```
var name = String()
```