# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, even if it is a Optional type

Tags: swift

I got an error I do not understand, as I thought I understood unwrapping a conditional var/let. But when I try to force unwrap it in the if I get the supplied error.

Error:

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'
```

Code:

```
let imNotSet: String?

print(type(of: imNotSet)) // Optional<String>

if let unwrappedVar = imNotSet! { // error on this line
    print(unwrappedVar)
}
```

Comment: Remove the exclamation mark ...

Comment: remove the `!` you are already force unwrapping it there

Comment: But then I get the error "Constant 'imNotSet' used before being initialized" that I would expect, so you can not use `let` to force unwrap?

Comment: Only optional *variables* are implicitly initialized to nil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400196/why-optional-constant-does-not-automatically-have-a-default-value-of-nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let unwrappedVar = imNotSet! { // error on this line
    print(unwrappedVar)
}
```

`imNotSet!` forcefully unwrapped imNotSet. So it is no longer an optional but rather a string.

To keep it an optional, remove the forced unwrapping.

```
if let unwrappedVar = imNotSet { // error fixed
        print(unwrappedVar)
    }
```

`if let` allows you to safely unwrap the optional, unlike the forced unwrapping that you were doing before.

As for `Constant 'imNotSet' used before being initialized` error,  Either provide it a value like `let imNotSet: String? = "Sample"`, if it truly is a constant, before you use it. Or make it a var if you need to reset it later like `var imNotSet: String? = nil`

Comment: So how does that work when I am using the `imNotSet` as a const? as now I get the error `Constant 'imNotSet' used before being initialized`

Comment: @BjörnHjorth Either provide it a value`let imNotSet: String? = "Sample"`
 if it truly is a constant before you use it, or make it a var if you need to reset it later `var imNotSet: String? = nil`.

Comment: So it's not possible to make a check for this situation: it's either nil or a constant value?

Comment: Pretty much. Optional Constants don't automatically default to nil as Martin said. Since you presumably need to change the value, you should use var anyways instead of let

Answer (score 1):

the `var` to be used with if let it must be an **optional** and this

```
imNotSet!
```

isn't , so replace

```
if let unwrappedVar = imNotSet! {
```

with

```
guard let unwrappedVar = imNotSet else { return }
```