# "Class has no initializers" error in Swift

Tags: swift

```
class Car {

let numWheels: Int

    init(numWheels: Int) {
        self.numWheels = numWheels
    }//end constructor
}//end class


class FastCar: Car {
    let topSpeed: Int
}//end class
```

why do I get an error saying "class 'FastCar' has no initializers"? I am an extreme beginner to the world of swift, and I feel like I just made a simple mistake but I went over it so many times I decided to come here.

Comment: Classes must be fully initialized when they are instantiated.  You either need to provide an initializer for FastCar or provide a value for topSpeed.  You'll need to initialize numWheels as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class has no initializers Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797351/class-has-no-initializers-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Because your FastCar class has a 'let' variable it needs to have a constructor or be given a value.

```
class FastCar: Car {
    let topSpeed: Int = 4
}
```

or

```
class FastCar: Car {
    let topSpeed: Int
    init(topSpeed: Int) {
        self.topSpeed = topSpeed
        super.init(numWheels: 4) // numWheels provided by init?
    }
}
```