# Swift - Class has no initializer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable to another view via code. When a user clicks on a table view data my app passes the table data to the next view. But I am getting a "class has no initialisers" on my second screen:

Table view calling 2nd screen on click:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{       
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editFriend") as! EditFriendViewController

self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

nextViewController.friend = friendArray[indexPath.row];
}
```

2nd screen code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class EditFriendViewController: UIViewController {

var friend: Friends

@IBOutlet weak var fName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mobile: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var gender: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fName.text = friend.firstName!;
    lName.text = friend.lastName!;
    mobile.text = friend.mobile!;
    address.text = friend.address!;   
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class has no initializers Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797351/class-has-no-initializers-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the answer of @Enix and @Shailesh,
I can see you are passing the data to `nextViewController`, after presenting the `viewController`,

Hence I don't think you will get the value in the nextVC, always you will get `nil` there.

So pass the data before presenting the viewController.

**Code to replace**

```
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
nextViewController.friend = friendArray[indexPath.row];
```

BY

```
nextViewController.friend = friendArray[indexPath.row];
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have defined a property without initialise it in your `init()` method. If you need a property to init in somewhere else instead of `init` method, eg. `viewDidLoad`. That is very common in ViewController. So you need to define the property as **implicitly unwrapped optional**, that means, you need to declare `friend` as `Friends!` instead of `Friends`, or if you need the property to be optional, then declare it as `Friend?`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class EditFriendViewController: UIViewController {
    var friend: Friends!  // declare friend as implicitly unwrapped optional, you are responsible to assign any value to it before using it
    ....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       friend = Friend() // Assign a value to friend property
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I got rid of the error. But now i can't seem to get the data in the friend object. Im getting a "unexpectedly found nil while unrwapping an optional value" error when I try to write the object's data into a text box.

Comment: @Janmenjaya give you hints about your issue. Try his answer. You should assign the value to friend before present the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make friend variable as optional

```
     var friend: Friends?
```

And while accessing the value use

```
   if let friend = friend {
       //use friend value to assign to values to label  }
```

Compiler is telling you friend variable has no initializer. All the variables of a class should have initial value via init method or they should be declared as optionals. And also semicolons are not mandatory in swift until you are writing to expression or statement in single line, so you can remove the semicolons at the end.