# How do I resolve error "Class appDelegate has no initializers"?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, appdelegate, init

I'm receiving the error:

> Class AppDelegate has no initializers

and cannot seem to understand why. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-Uwa5v_3sc). I am a beginner so any help would be VERY appreciated!

My code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var centerContainer: MMDrawerController

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        _ = self.window!.rootViewController

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

        let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController

        let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)


        centerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)


        centerContainer.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView;

        centerContainer.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView;

        window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `centerContainer` need to be a property? Will it be access from other code besides the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class has no initializers Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797351/class-has-no-initializers-swift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing your `centerContainer` property to an *optional* like this:

```
var centerContainer: MMDrawerController!
```

as such, it will be initialized with `nil`, which should be enough to remove the error you are having. (By the way, you shouldn't need to change the rest of your code as a result.)

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) book:

> Classes and structures *must* set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties *cannot* be left in an indeterminate state.

Answer (score 4):

Since `centerContainer` isn't an optional and isn't given a default value, Swift expects an initializer function to give it one.  There are a few possible solutions here:

1. Give it a default value.  Probably not practical in this context.
2. Make it optional.  Would work, but depending on how it's used might add a lot of unnecessary unwrapping to your code.
3. Make it an implicitly unwrapped optional.  This is essentially saying "I can't/don't want to give this a default value or set it in an initializer, but I will definitely be giving it a value before I use it for anything."  Usually the cleanest option for things like this, just be careful that you don't assign it `nil` at any point later in your code or things will break.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `centerContainer` var optional like `window`. In swift, all of the properties must be initialized. When you make your var optional, you are initializing it as `nil`.

```
var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?
```

Comment: Using an *implicitly unwrapped* optional here (ie, `MMDrawerController!`) might be a better fit here. See my answer below.

Comment: @PauloMattos Yes! That's absolutely right. But as the OP had some basic knowledge on `optional` (he had used one as `window`) I hope _not bragging some more concept_(that is, `implicit optional`) would be good for him.

Comment: Good point man, I agree! A *concepts overload* -- a common behavior on SO, one may say -- might scary him away. Sometimes you need to learn a trick at time :)