# In Swift, didSet doesn’t fire when invoked from init()

Tags: swift

I’ve got a car and a driver. They mutually reference each other. In the car’s init() I create a driver and assign it to the driver member. The driver member has a didSet method which is supposed to set the driver’s car, thus mutually link them to each other.

```
class GmDriver {
    var car: GmCar! = nil
}

class GmCar {
    var driver: GmDriver {
        didSet {
            driver.car = self
        }
    }
    init() {
        driver = GmDriver()
    }
}

let myCar = GmCar()
println(myCar.driver.car) // nil
```

However, the didSet never fires. Why?

Comment: Property observers are not called during init, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift

Comment: Thanks! Missing both Apple's documentation and searching stackoverflow really should earn me minus reputation...

Comment: @MartinR please add that as an answer, maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to allow didSet to be called during initialization in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift)

Answer (score 51):

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

> The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called.

Answer (score 3):

```
init() {
    defer {
        driver = GmDriver()
    }
}
```