# Swift trigger didSet when init

Tags: swift, init, didset

Why this code will trigger didSet when init

```
final public class TestDidSet {

static var _shared: TestDidSet! = TestDidSet()

func testA() { }

private var test = true {
    didSet {
        print("didSet test when initing!!!!!:\(test)")
    }
}
private var _value: Bool! {
    didSet {
        print("didSet when initing!!!!!:\(_value)")
    }
}

private init() {
    testSet()
    _value = false
    test = false
}

private func testSet() {
    _value = true
}
}

TestDidSet._shared.testA()
```

any idea?
should it not trigger didSet?
someone help!

update:
My point of view is this,
`testSet()` and `_value = false` is doing the same thing, but `testSet()` is outside `init()`, so `testSet()` will trigger `didSet` while `_value = false` not. Why?!

It's not optional type or other reason, that cause 'didSet', I suppose.

Comment: What do you want ? call testSet() will trigger your didSet, while assign value will not trigger your didSet in init function

Comment: [This comment explains it nicely.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift#comment39303335_25231068)

Comment: `didSet` is a setter in Swift same `- (void)setTest:(Bool)test;` in Objective-C. So it will call when you will assign any value to `test`. Its not an event its a setter.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a property with an implicitly unwrapped optional type (`Bool!` in your case), it gets implicitly assigned a default value of `nil`.  Then afterwards if you assign it with some other value in your initializer then the `didSet` observer gets triggered because it's already a *second* assignment.  `didSet` is supposed to not be triggered only on a first one.

Comment: It's nothing about how many time I using `_value = false`, it'll always not trigger `didSet` while this code is in `init()`

Comment: Yes, because the type of property is `Bool!`.  If you change it to simple `Bool` (and make necessary adjustment for not being allowed to trigger instance methods before all properties were initialized), then you will notice that the very first assignment does not trigger the observer, and all consequent do.

Answer (score -3):

The `didSet{}` closure is called **every time you assign a new value** to your properties (even if you assign it at the declaration (inline) or at the initialisation).

Comment: `The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called.`, see: [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262)