# DidSet not working in init function swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I have already seen

[Is it possible to allow didSet to be called during initialization in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift)

for me it is not working..

I am working in project where I have created class below

```
protocol FileManagerHelper {

    var fileName:String {get}
    var fileCategory:FileCategory {get set}
    var isFileExitsAtPath:Bool {get}
    var filePath:String {get}
    var fileType:FileTypes {get set}

}

class FileManager:FileManagerHelper {
    // Other property 

    //STORED PROPERY INIT WHEN OBJECT WILL CREATED WITH FileCategory OBJECT 
     var fileCategory:FileCategory  {
    didSet {
        switch fileCategory {
        case .XYZ:
            print("Test")


        ... other cases 
         }
     }

    required init(fileCategory:FileCategory,fileType:FileTypes = .Image) {

        self.fileCategory = fileCategory
        self.path = self.folderPath + self.fileName

   }

 }
```

did set method is not calling of  `fileCategory`

NOTE:  I don't want to give default value , I want to pass it runtime from `init` method

Tries

1) `defer`

> use of self in method called $defer before all stored property are initialised

2) Create custom method that will assign that value and call it from init

```
 private func setCategory(with category:FileCategory) {
    self.fileCategory = category
}
```

> Use of method call setCategory before stored property ...

I know that all stored property should be initialised  before instance created. Till that instance will not been created so i won't call methods (using self) may be that why above solution not working

Please help me if any one have idea

Comment: according to apple documents -: The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called.

Comment: @TusharSharma  Agree !!  Thanks for your efforts but please check link i have added where the property is calling didSet with defer keyword so it looks like possible to initialise in property (with didSet) in self within in the init method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, using the `defer` is better readable.

```
import Foundation

class A {
    var b: String {
        didSet {
            print("didSet called with value: \(b)")
        }
    }

    init(x: String) {
        self.b = x
        defer { self.b = x }
    }
}

let a = A(x: "It's Working!") // didSet called with value: It's Working!
print(a.b) // It's Working
```

Comment: Why Two times  self.b = x ?

Comment: First time to satisfy the compiler, second time to call the `didSet`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to extract the `didSet` logic into a separate method and call this method from both `didSet` and `init`:

```
class FileManager: FileManagerHelper {

  var fileCategory:FileCategory  {
    didSet {
      didSetFileCategory()
    }
  }

  required init(fileCategory:FileCategory,fileType:FileTypes = .Image) {
    self.fileCategory = fileCategory
    self.path = self.folderPath + self.fileName
    didSetFileCategory()
  }

  private func didSetFileCategory() {
    switch fileCategory {
    case .XYZ:
      print("Test")
    //... other cases 
    }
  }
}
```