# Struct not calling property observers on new object

Tags: swift, struct, computed-properties, didset, property-observer

In this code, I would like to have the `property observers` called when the new object is created. How do I achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myValue: Int {
        willSet {
            print("willSet")
        }
        didSet {
            print("didSet")
        }
    }
}

var abc = MyStruct(myValue: 3) // Does not use property observers
abc.myValue = 5 // Calls property observers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a custom initializer as follows.

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myValue: Int {
        willSet {
            print("willSet")
        }
        didSet {
            print("didSet")
        }
    }

    init(value: Int) {
        myValue = value
        // print something here
    }
}

var abc = MyStruct(value: 3) 
abc.myValue = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the first is an instance **creation** - you don't **set** the property as the name suggests. If you need something to happen on instance creation just do it in the init method like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    init(myValue: Int) {
        self.myValue = myValue
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's on purpose that property observers are not called in initializers. Consider the code below; the program would crash if this `struct` was made an instance of. That's because the observers access other properties before they have been set. Because of this, it was chosen not to have observers run from initializers.

```
struct Struct {

    var p1: Int { didSet { p2 = p3 * 2 } }
    var p2: Int { didSet { p1 = p3 / 2 } }
    var p3: Int

    init(_ p1: Int, _ p2: Int, _ p3: Int) {
        self.p1 = p1 // The program crashes at this point, because `p3` was not yet set.
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3
    }
}
```

To circumvent this, you can create a function that you call from both the observers and the initializer, or you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift).