# Why is didSet called when set inside an initializer?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm playing around with SwiftUI and I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Foo: ObservableObject {

    @Published var foo: Int! { // Implicit unwrapped optional
        didSet {
            print("foo")
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.foo = 1
    }
}
```

The didSet is always called. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) it should not be called. Is there something special going on with the `@Published` property wrapper?

Comment: Tested on Xcode 11.2.1 - `didSet` is not called during initialise in your code snapshot. As well as w/o `@Published`.

Comment: I've tested on Xcode 11.3 (11C29) - `didSet` is not called during initialize in your code snapshot (as @Asperi wrote)

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Check updated code in question. @Asperi

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The rule is that setter observers are not called during initialization. But by the time you set this property, initialization is over! The property was already given its *initial* value, namely `nil`.  Therefore even though you are in an `init` method, you are not “during initialization” and the setter observer runs.

Comment: Why this answer accepted? This is not correct answer

Answer (score 2):

All about types... Ok, let's consider code...

**case 1:** `@Published var foo: Int`

is actually

```
var foo: Int
var _foo: Published<Int>
```

so

```
init() {
    self.foo = 1 // << Initialization
}
```

**case 2:** `@Published var foo: Int!` (the same will be for `@Published var foo: Int?`)

is actually

```
var foo: Int!
var _foo: Published<Int?> // !! Not primitive - generics class, types differ
```

so

```
init() {
    self.foo = 1 // << Assignment of Int(1)
}
```

Thus, IMO, answer is yes, it is something special about @Published.

*Note*: You can see all picture in run-time if set breakpoint at `self.foo = 1` line and using ^F7 (Control-Step Into) go by instruction for both cases... very interesting internals.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer here, when using implicit unwrapped variable it leaves the initialised scope therefor didSet is called: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25231068/294661