# UIView not initialised with model

Tags: swift, uiview

I'm setting up a UIView with a cardModel in this way:

```
var cardModel : CardModel!{
    didSet{
        nameLabel.text = cardModel!.name
    }
}


init(frame: CGRect, cardModel: CardModel) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    
    self.cardModel = cardModel
    
    setUpUI()
    
    setUpGestureRecognizers()
    
    setUpPlayer()
    
}
```

The problem is that the variable cardModel didSet is not called I actually don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didSet` isn't called because you are initializing `carModel` in `init`.  So to get it work, you could put the initialization of `carModel` inside a closure like so:

```
init(frame: CGRect, cardModel: CardModel) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    ({ self.cardModel = cardModel })()
    
    //...
}
```

For further information: [Is it possible to allow didSet to be called during initialization in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift)