# UIButton property observers didset never called

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a simple button in a cocoapods library, I need to change the tintcolor when it is `isHighlighted` however isHighlighted gets called but didset or willset never get called.

I am ofcourse setting my button to be highlighted, and I call this function after I dequeue my tableview cell

```
func setupCell() {
    let myCustomButton = UIButton.button(title: "Button")
    myCustomButton.isHighlighted = true
}
```

My UIButton Extension

```
extension UIButton {

    public static func button(title: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
        return button
    }

  override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
      didSet {
          print("Never gets here, ever!")
      } 
   }
}
```

How can I trigger didSet? Is there any other way apart from setting isHighlighted to true?

Comment: I tried the code it's working where do you write button's initialization code ??  maybe the code just not called .

Comment: Are you calling ```myCustomButton.isHighlighted = true``` inside an ```init```?

Comment: In case you do, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift

Comment: @finebel I don't have it in an init, I actually have it in a function which I call after dequeue my tableview cell