# Why here use a closures to set value for shader's uniform?

Tags: swift, closures, gpuimage

I'm looking at GPUImage3,
My question is why closures are used here instead of direct assignments

```
public class LuminanceThreshold: BasicOperation {
    public var threshold:Float = 0.5 { didSet { uniformSettings["threshold"] = threshold } }
    
    public init() {
        super.init(fragmentFunctionName: "thresholdFragment", numberOfInputs:1)
        
        ({threshold = 0.5})() //this line
    }
}
```

I want to know why and how it works.

Comment: Related question: [Is it possible to allow didSet to be called during initialization in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230780/is-it-possible-to-allow-didset-to-be-called-during-initialization-in-swift)